# GitHub for Windows not recognizing new files

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have a repo to which I have been adding and updating code on a regular basis for the last few months.  I just created two new java files.  I did a github commit  and sync.  I noticed on github.com the files did not show up.
I then noticed they do not appear on GitHub Windows.  I then created more files and they do not appear in in GitHub either.
Other pre-existing files that have been modified, correctly appear in GitHub and are updated.

I have tried:

- Looked at .gitignore. 
  The path or filenames do not appear in the file.
- Looked at .git/info/exclude.  File is empty.
- git status says:

  > On branch master
  >   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
  >   nothing to commit, working directory clean
- In git shell, ls shows the files in the directory
- However, git ls-files -v does not list the files.

How do I get github to start recognizing newly created files?

Comment: If you run `git fetch` then `git log -p origin/master`, what do you see? Do you see patch changes in the log?

Comment: No.  I see an <entry > tag in the file, but no differences like I do for other changes.  I would add that if I create a new random Java file, that does not show up in Github either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have untracked java files, try

```
git add *.java
```

Then `git commit` and push code to repo.....

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  It said "The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:"  Adding -f to the command line fixed it.  I have looked at the .ignore file, but don't understand how it is interfering.  Sorry, forgot to mention I am using Android Studio.  It usually handles this, but this must not have occurred and I didn't realize it.

Comment: Well, I thought it worked.  No complaints from Git, but still not on GitHub.  Tried deleting files from within Android Studio and re-adding.  No luck.

Comment: I have the same problem few days back...I had to change the directory then it worked....

Comment: I just uninstalled GH, then removed related files from the project and from users/xxx/appdata/local/git etc, then reinstalled.  Never understood the actual cause of the problem.